# lambda function node.js http request can't view response

Tags: node.js, lambda

I've got the following lambda function which seems to work and returns a 200 code. However, when I try to print the response from the GET request I see a very long IncomingMessage object and none if the data being fetched is visible. I can see the server activity, and that this GET request is correctly hitting the server to fetch data via the GET request, but none of this data is visible.

Is it possible the data is nested and I'm just not seeing it?

My lambda function:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('https');

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
        host: 'www.somehost.com',
        path: '/somepath',
        headers: {
          'Authorization':'Bearer someBearerToken'
        },
        method: 'GET'
    };

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log("success! data is: ", res)
      resolve(res);
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    }); 

    // send the request
    req.write('');
    req.end();
});
```

Comment: when you test it in AWS console, what do you get?

Comment: @AIqbal when I deploy and run a test and this prints in CloudWatch I get the same IncomingMessage and lots of info but I can't see my Data. Also interestingly,  it says the test failed even tho status code is 200. Running locally with serverless offline I also get a 200.

Comment: i mean that you check the response when you test your lambda function from the AWS console... take a look at "Invoke the Lambda Function Manually and Verify Results, Logs, and Metric" on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-create-function.html to see what i mean...

Comment: @AIqbal In AWS I'm getting the error: {
  "errorMessage": "Converting circular structure to JSON",  "errorType": "TypeError",  "stackTrace": []}. I can't seem to find info on what this means.

Comment: print the response from http.request... const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
/* just print the response...*/      console.log(res)
    });... Also, before  reject(e.message), try console.log(e)... this will show you the error object with details which will help you pinpoint the issue